# How to display multiple triangles using a pseudo element on a th table header

Tags: html, html-table

I want to add two triangles using pseudo elements after the text in a table header cell. You guessed it, they would represent that the column is sortable. Of course, I can do that using a background image but I want to avoid that traditional solution.

I can add one triangle using the pseudo element :after. That's easy. I cannot use pseudo element :before to add the other triangle because it is placed before the text in the "th" element. If I have to position it, using the :before pseudo element, to be placed after the text, that will not work as a generic solution because each column header has, of course, different text.

Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: Certainly deserve the downvote. The "right" positioning just skipped my mind. I am so used to thinking only along top,left positioning... @gvee's answer instantly switched that light on!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wfc8/**

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Short</th>
        <th>Really much longer</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
th {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

th:after,
th:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
th:after {
    top: -2px;
    border-bottom-color: lime;
}
th:before {
    top: 10px;
    border-top-color: lime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect!!! The "right" positioning just skipped my mind. I am so used to the left,top positioning only.

Comment: Does not work in Firefox!!

Comment: @Samir appears to be a known bug in FF: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895

Comment: @Samir can get it to work in FF by adding an extra wrapping element: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wfc8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/RH5eA/)**</kbd>

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
</table>

th {
  width: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
th:after {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 10px;
  line-height: 11px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #0296cc;
  content: '▲ ▼';
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I am not sure about the portability/font availability or color setting (just like any font?) issues if any in this solution. Otherwise, this is certainly a much simpler and clear solution.

Comment: You can set the `font-family` & `color` if that's what you ask. I just tested above code in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE, works fine in all.

Comment: How do I specify those characters?

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean how to insert them, here's a [link](http://brucejohnson.ca/SpecialCharacters.html "Special Characters").

Comment: Thanks. Good on all fronts! Learned something different too...